# Tmux - Get number of panes in the current window in bash variable?

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm scripting Tmux, and would like to know the number of panes in the current window from a bash script.

Is there anyway to find out this information?

in pseudo code, i'd like something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=$(tmux get_number_of_panes)
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might be a better way, but

```
tmux list-panes | wc -l
```

works.

Comment: In one command: `tmux display-message -p '#{window_panes}'` (see the FORMATS section of the man page for other variables).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Right on. Easy to miss because it's not in the `pane_` group